# Getting Average for Weekdays and Weekends within 30 days in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the average repairs in  the weekdays and weekends within the last 30 days. Each day is tagged whether it's a weekday or a weekend. Holidays are tagged as weekends.

If I use:

```sql
AVG(Completed_Repairs) OVER(PARTITION BY day_type ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(WORK_DT) RANGE BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

I only get either the average repairs for all weekdays or for all weekends in the last 30 days depending on what type of day the date is. But I also need the average for the opposite to compute a prorated monthly number. I basically would need another column with the value of the opposite day type.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, not partitioning might be the way:

```
with
input as (
  select cast('2022-10-11' as date) as WORK_DT, "weekday" as day_type, 307 as completed_repairs union all
  select cast('2022-10-12' as date) as WORK_DT, "weekday" as day_type, 100 as completed_repairs union all
  select cast('2022-10-09' as date) as WORK_DT, "weekend" as day_type, 750 as completed_repairs union all
  select cast('2022-10-10' as date) as WORK_DT, "weekend" as day_type, 647 as completed_repairs 
)
select 
  *,
  avg(if(day_type = 'weekday', completed_repairs,0)) OVER(ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(WORK_DT) RANGE BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as avg_weekday,
  avg(if(day_type = 'weekend', completed_repairs,0)) OVER(ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(WORK_DT) RANGE BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as avg_weekend,
from input
order by work_dt
```

You can replace the 0 by *null* if you don't want the weekends to impact the average of the weekdays and vice-versa.
If you'd rather have a column "matching" and a column "opposite" you can then use the result of this to write a condition depending on the day_type and the column name.